# Request using fetch returns "typeerror: response.json is not a function" (ReactJS/node;express0

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, fetch-api

I'm developing a webpage with reactjs and a simple REST api/database with nodejs and I'm trying to properly use this API of mine from the front end. It was supposed to send a json containing {username,email, password} and return the infos of this new registration. I'm using express in my API and my create(POST) method is working as I've tested on a GUI API client. Here's my  post request in my API:

```
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
try {
    const { email } = req.body;

    if (await User.findOne({ email }))
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'E-mail already registered' });

    const user = await User.create(req.body);

    user.password = undefined;

    return res.json({ user, token: generateToken({ id: user._id }) });
}
catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Registration failed' })
}
});
```

and in my front end app I'm using the fetch method to call my API, here it is:

```
    create = async () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/auth/register", {
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": 'application/json'
        },
        "body": JSON.stringify({
            "username": "test",
            "email": "test@gmail.com",
            "password": "test"
        })
    })
        .then(res => Response.json()) //<< The problem is here
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
}
```

but when I call this create method on my front end I'm getting the error:
TypeError: Response.json is not a function

I understand the parameter of then must be a function but I'm not sure I should be treating the response in another way. Does someone know why this happens?

Comment: Call `.json` on the argument passed, not on the `window.Response` constructor

Comment: Try `res.json()` instead of `Response.json()`

Comment: Replace `Responce.json()` with `res.json()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by the others, and, in fact, by yourself, the `Response.json()` is incorrect. You should be calling the `json()` function on the response object as in `res => res.json()`. This way, the next `then` gets the JSON response body as an object and you can access it like this `json.token`

An alternative way to call that `json()` function would be like so:

```
...
.then(res => {
    res.json().then(json => {
       //Do stuff with json here
    })
}) 
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

And skip adding a second `then` to the `fetch` call. The difference is certainly immaterial but is meant to illustrate the point.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the name of the param that you create, like this:

```
res => res.json()
```